# Rank each row in a data frame in descending order

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

I want to apply `rank()` to each row in a data frame by `apply(data.frame,1,rank)`. However, rank is by default ascending. So when I apply rank() to my first row with the values (2,1,3,5), I get

```
[1] 2 1 3 4
```

However, I want

```
[1] 3 4 2 1
```

How can I do this using `apply(data.frame,1,rank)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
apply(-data, 1, rank, ties.method='first')
```

and compare with

```
apply(data, 1, rank, ties.method='first')
```

For your specific example

```
v1 <- c(2,1,3,5)
rank(v1)
#[1] 2 1 3 4
rank(-v1)
#[1] 3 4 2 1
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 4*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
```